Using TapLinx sdk with IOS
I'm trying to integrate Mifare taplinx sdk with my react native app. Currently, android is done ok, but ios giving me this error when run:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

the project can be built with no errors, but does give me this error. any help is much appreciated

Hi,
I'm experiencing the same issue while integrating the MIFARE TapLinx SDK, but with a native iOS app. My Android integration works fine, but on iOS, I encounter the following error at runtime:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
The project builds without any errors, but this error occurs during execution. Have you found any solution or workaround for this issue? Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Hi, unfortunately the sdk for iOS doesnt work so i had to use the apdu commands instead
